# How are pointers resolved across heaps in C++

Tags: c++, memory, dll

I am basically calling a C++ DLL using **LoadLibrary()** in my C++ application. The application causes random **0xc0000005 (Access violation)** Errors. I have done a lot of study on DLL's having their own heaps and their problems.

Things I've made sure to do so far:

> In the DLL :
>
> 1. All allocations are done in C++ standards. (no usage of malloc or calloc)
> 2. All new's have a reachable equivalent delete.
> 3. There is no memory allocated inside the DLL that is freed in the Host exe or   vice versa.
> 4. Data transfer between the two is done via POD (char* specifically). No STL's.
> 5. All exported function's have a calling convention of **__stdcall**
> 6. The DLL is built specifying extern "C" and a DEF file.
>
> In the Host Exe:
>
> 1. Allocated memory using **HeapAlloc()** with **GetProcessHeap()**
> 2. The pointer is passed to the DLL which copies bytes on it using 
>      **memcpy()**
> 3. DLL function typedef's are correct.
> 4. Compilers for both the DLL and the exe are same.(built in VS2010).

The crashes occur at random locations :

1. While debugging I observed that just as we step over "**}**" function end brace in the DLL, the exception occurs.
2. After successfully returning from the DLL call. Crash occurs randomly.

All the Event logs show **"Faulting module name"** to be the **DLL**.

Taking into account all the points that I have stated previously, I would appreciate if anyone guided me on where to look for cause of the exception.

Also does the pointer I send to the DLL get resolved to the correct HEAP in **memcpy()**?. The data is correct in the host exe though. **GetProcessHeaps()** return 4 HEAPS.

**EDIT**
Cannot post the full code due to policies. (again, make note that I have accounted for most of the common mistakes made).

Function where the error occurs (DLL)

```
extern "C"  void __stdcall BuildApplicationsList();
```

Typedef in exe

```
typedef void(__stdcall *buildAppsList)(void);
```

**UPDATE**

In response to @RalfFriedl. You were right!. the program crashes in this location.

}

```
5822593F  mov         byte ptr [esp+7A0h],7  
58225947  cmp         dword ptr [esp+0A0h],0  
5822594F  jne         BuildApplicationsList+1CE2h (58225992h)  
58225951  mov         eax,dword ptr [esp+74h]  
58225955  test        eax,eax  
58225957  je          BuildApplicationsList+1CB1h (58225961h)  
58225959  mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax]  
5822595B  mov         edx,dword ptr [ecx+8]    // Crash Occurs here. 
5822595E  push        eax  
5822595F  call        edx  
58225961  mov         eax,dword ptr [esp+70h]  
58225965  test        eax,eax  
58225967  je          BuildApplicationsList+1CC1h (58225971h)  
58225969  mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax]  
5822596B  mov         edx,dword ptr [ecx+8]  
5822596E  push        eax  
5822596F  call        edx  
58225971  mov         eax,dword ptr [esp+6Ch]  
58225975  test        eax,eax  
58225977  je          BuildApplicationsList+1CD1h (58225981h)  
58225979  mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax]  
5822597B  mov         edx,dword ptr [ecx+8]  
5822597E  push        eax  
5822597F  call        edx  
58225981  call        dword ptr [__imp__CoUninitialize@0 (5823F2C8h)]
```

**edx and ecx are 0** and obviously accessing 0x00000008 is a violation.
Where to next?

Comment: The Windows "heaps" are parts of the same memory space - there's no need to "resolve" pointers. These heaps have nothing to do with the thing people call "heap" in C++.

Comment: The next place to look is `BuildApplicationsList`. (`CoUninitialize` in a DLL looks a bit strange, by the way.)

Comment: Something has become badly corrupted somehow - you have an object with a null vtable pointer. My first guess would be that the object in question has been destroyed and then overwritten, or never properly created. You're retrieving a pointer to that object from a local variable.

Comment: @molbdnilo I was using a WMI helper from http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/41301-c-easy-to-use-wmi-implementation/ . I commented out the entire WMI segment and it does not crash anymore. Strange. The same DLL used in another scaffolding application does not produce the same exception. What went wrong and where .. i wonder

Comment: @molbdnilo Where can you identify that the vtable is null in the assembly dump? Can you kindly elaborate on that point.

Comment: `mov ecx,dword ptr [eax]`: fetch the vtable pointer from the object at `eax`; `mov edx,dword ptr [ecx+8]`: fetch the function pointer at offset 8 in the vtable; `push eax `: add the `this` argument; `call edx:` call the function. `eax` isn't zero, but `edx` is, so the vtable pointer must be null.

Comment: But "ecx" should be equal to "eax" after the first mov. which isnt the case. as you mentioned. eax is'nt zero. but "ecx" is. which means it does not even assign anything to edx. It crashes before the line  "mov edx, dword ptr [ecx + 8]" is finished. [ecx + 8] is 0x00008 but "eax" is some valid pointer.  @molbdnilo

Comment: `mov ecx, dword ptr [eax]` retrieves the value at the address `eax`, not the value of `eax`. (That is, it's dereferencing a pointer.)

Comment: Oh! Got it! @molbdnilo I will try to sniff out what is causing that vtable issue.!

Comment: On a side note: when you need to match an assembly listing with a C++ source listing, identifying the virtual function calls is a surprisingly effective way of finding your way around.

Comment: Just realised that I wrote `edx` when I meant `ecx` in the comment that explains the virtual function call. Too late to edit, but I might as well nitpick myself.

Comment: I've encountered a similar problem. It's on the Windows platform. I have a third party omniORB DLL built with Visual Studio 2008. My app is built with Visual Studio 2013. At runtime, my app has a reference variable to an omniORB CORBA object created by omniORB DLL. Memory corruption occurs when the omniORB CORBA object falls out of scope in my app. The issue is that the omniORB CORBA object got allocated on the DLL's heap. So when my app calls the omniORB CORBA object's destructor (the call is compiler generated due to hitting function end), it's trying to free the object using the app's heap.

Answer (score 0):

When you step over the end of the function, the local destructors are called. Switch to debugging the assembler code and find out which destructor causes the problem.

You issue is probably not related to the separation between main program and DLL, but just a reference to an invalidated pointer that might occur anyway.

**Edit**

```
58225951  mov         eax,dword ptr [esp+74h]  
58225955  test        eax,eax  
58225957  je          BuildApplicationsList+1CB1h (58225961h)  
58225959  mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax]  
5822595B  mov         edx,dword ptr [ecx+8]    // Crash Occurs here.
```

At `esp+74h` you have a local variable, it seems to be a pointer to a class with virtual function. The value of this pointer is nonzero. But as destructors are not called for the target of a pointer, you probably have a class that encapsulates a pointer and calls `delete` on the pointer from the class destructor. The problem is probably that the destructor for the target object has already been called and the space freed.

Just before stepping into the end of the function, find out the value of `esp+74h`. That is the address `esp+74h`, not the value stored at that address. Check the addresses of all local variables. On of them must be equal to `esp+74h`. This is the destructor that causes the problem.

You could also try to disable inlining. Then your debugger probably stops at the correct place.

Comment: Will do that and get back to you!

Comment: Updated the Question @RalfFriedl